Save private key passphrase OpenVPN on debian
I installed the OpenVPN 3 client on my debian bookworm, but every time I start the daemon it says Private key passphrase:.
How can I store the passphrase? It's annoying type the password every time I boot. The OpenVPN Connect Client for Windows has the option Save Private Key Password, but I don't find any similar in the terminal client for linux.
The OpenVPN Server runs on a MikroTik RouterOS 7.15.2.
The client configuration is:
dev tun
proto tcp-client
remote *****.com
port 1194
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
client
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
verb 6
mute 10
cipher AES-256-GCM
redirect-gateway def1
auth SHA1

<auth-user-pass>
*****
*****
</auth-user-pass>

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>


Remove the passphrase from the key?

Do you have a valid reason to have it encrypted? Then, probably, that reason would advocate the use of the token instead or storing in files. See this question also, maybe it'll have a clue.
